# How to read a CSV file and skip the header row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the following code

```
import csv

with open('skill.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    # next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Here is what the csv contains:

```
Skill,amount_of_skill
First aid,50
Stealth,40
```

It outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('Skill', 'First aid'), ('amount_of_skill', '50')])
OrderedDict([('Skill', 'Stealth'), ('amount_of_skill', '40')])
```

How do I get it to just say:

```
First Aid    50
Stealth   40
```

Comment: Why do you read the lines in a dictionary in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You are reading as a ***dict*** but you need a simple csv.

Here is as it should be:

```
import csv
with open('skill.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader) #to skip header
    for line in csv_reader:
        print('  '.join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't access the `values` of the dictionary, you just print the dictionary that holds the data for each line.

```
with open("skill.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        print(" ".join(line.values()))
```

Output:

```
First aid 50
Stealth 40
```

You could also use the unpacking operator (`*`) in the print statement:

```
print(*line.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the csv file into a dictionary.

You don't need any library to read the csv..
You can just open the file and split the fields by comma:

```
with open('skill.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv_file.readlines()


for line in csv_reader:
    print(line.replace(',', ' '))
```

Output:

```
First aid 50
Stealth 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely for fun ... if you wanted to smash it all into one line, you could do:

```
print(*[i.replace(',', ' ') for i in open('skills.csv').readlines()[1:]], sep='')
```

Output:

```
First aid 50
Stealth 40
```

Readable ... not really.  Fun? Yes!

---

Something more readable:

```
with open('skills.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]

print(*[i.replace(',', ' ') for i in lines], sep='')
```